# SQL Server trigger for 'Default (newsequentialid())' not working with '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'?

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, guid, bcs

I have an Entity with a Guid column as the primary key.

Its default is (`newsequentialid()`). So if I pass NULL it will generate the Guid.

Now I use this database with BDC Model Stuff. The problem is that this auto generated code doesn't pass NULL for the ID with new objects on creation, instead it uses probably just `new Guid()` which is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. So my default constraint is not working and I get a primary key constraint violation error...

So is it possible to catch this problem with a trigger? Maybe check first if the Id is 0000...0 and then generate a valid one?

Comment: How are you passing the values from C# code, You don't have to use Triggers for this. You can fix that in your C# code.

Comment: > So is it possible to catch this problem with a trigger? 

Yes. Should you do it? No. Fix the problem at the source, in your 'BCS Model Stuff', whatever that means. If you have a leaking pipe the fix is not to provide a drain in your floor, the fix is to plumb the leak.

Answer (score 1):

You can use triggers, although as others have pointed out, this would be an unwise solution, as introduces an unseen hack between code and data. Your real solution is to change your ORM such that it doesn't attempt to insert the `GUID` directly, as this is database generated.

So ignore the remainder of my answer.

> SqlServer doesn't support BEFORE triggers, but you could use an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`
>
>      CREATE TRIGGER tSomeTable  ON SomeTable INSTEAD OF INSERT
>      AS
>         BEGIN
>            INSERT INTO SomeTable(SomeKey, Name)
>               SELECT
>                  CASE WHEN i.SomeKey = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
>                       THEN newid() ELSE i.SomeKey END,
>                  i.Name
>               FROM INSERTED i;
>         END

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26315/2)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `Guid.NewGuid()` which generates a valid Guid.

Comment: If you provide your existing code, could be helpful for solving your issue. Because, there would be a way to set the `id` value by code.